# Jenkinsでジョブを実行した時、シェルを実行している権限は？

Tags: macos, jenkins, shellscript

シェルスクリプトの中にNodeJsをインストールするコマンドが書いてあり、
Jenkinsのジョブを実行するとそのスクリプトが実行されます。

Jenkinsのジョブを使用して実行すると
コンソール出力に下記のメッセージが出ていてNodeJsがインストールされません。

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

しかし、vncを使用して遠隔ログインしターミナルを立ち上げて
シェルスクリプトを実行するとエラーが出ずインストールが完了します。

vncログインしたものと全く同じログインをしたユーザーの環境上で
Jenkinsは起動しているのですが、Jenkins自体は別の権限？で動作しているのでしょうか？

■環境
MacOSX:10.10.3

【追記】
大事なことを書き忘れてました
visudoで下記を追加はしたのですが失敗します。

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/visudo
------------------------
# Defaults requiretty           # tty無しの場合sudoさせない
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty   # ユーザjenkinsはtty無しでsudo可能
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL # ユーザjenkinsはパスワード無しでsudo可能
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkinsのジョブはデフォルトだとjenkinsというユーザで実行されているようなので、jenkinsというユーザの権限を確認してみてください（デフォルトだとルート権限は無いと思います）。また、Jenkinsのジョブの実行ユーザはシェルの中でwhoamiコマンドを叩くなどすれば確認出来ます。

なお、該当エラーメッセージへの対処方法は以下が参考になると思います。
http://qiita.com/ykirishima/items/2f32dae7fa28a2b45801

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、visudoでJenkinsにsudo権限パスワードなしを与えているのにインストールに失敗するのでなぜかなと思ってました。　whoamiコマンドでチェックしてみます。